# observe a click event in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

In the original version of my controller, I added a header logo to the dom and then was able to remove and replace it with something else when a function was called, like this

```
    $scope.addHeader('.blahClassName');

    $scope.removeHeaderFunction = function(){
          $('.blahClassName).html('');
          //do other stuff
    }
```

This worked fine. However, I read that it's better not to do DOM manipulation in the controller, therefore I created a directive like this

```
<div class='MyCtrl as vm'>
 <div header-dir myscope="vm" removeheaderflag="{{vm.headerflag}}"></div>
```

Then, inside the link function of my directive, I add the header logo and listen for a change in the flag to remove it, like this

```
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

       scope.myscope.addHeader('.blahClassName'); //calling the function addHeader on the controller available through myscope

       attrs.$observe('removeheaderflag', function(){
           angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('.blahClassName')).html('');
       });         
  }
```

Then in the controller, I set `$scope.headerflag = null;` on page load, and set it to true in the `removeHeaerFunction` with the intention that it would remove the header only when the flag was set to true

```
 $scope.removeHeaderFunction = function(){
    $scope.headerflag = true;
  }
```

However, the actual behavior of my code is that the logo is added and removed immediately, no matter what `$scope.headerflag` is set to. In other words, the code inside `$attrs.observe('removeheaderflag', ...` is run immediately.

Question: how to delay the running of the code in that observer or otherwise get the behavior that I desire from within the directive, i.e. basically to be able to remove something on a click event

Comment: Are you using standard click events or ng-click? It sounds like you are not setting the controller values from inside the angular lifecycle thus the changes are not immediately reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$observe` does works same as that of `$watch` the only difference between this two is `$observe` works on interpolation expression `{{}}` and `$watch` works on scope value as string.

Currently what happening is your `$observe` function gets called when your variable `removeheaderflag` from `undefined` to `null` so in this case the `$observe` callback function is getting called and your `blahClassName` class getting removed from the DOM. For restricting this behavior you should add condition to call your desired code when `removeheaderflag` changed value to `true`

**Code**

```
attrs.$observe('removeheaderflag', function(newVal, oldValue){
  if(newVal) //this will check values in not null & not false
   angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('.blahClassName')).html('');
});
```

Comment: I thought we only had a handle on `newValue` and `oldValue` in a `$watch` where `$observe` will only afford us the value

Comment: Thank you. Do you agree with this approach to set state on the controller and listen/observe changes to the state in the directive to then do dom manipulation?

Comment: @Leahcim I would prefer to use `ng-class` there..will add class on basis of  the model changes like `ng-class="{'blahClassName': headerflag}"`

Comment: but can I then listen for class changes and trigger dom events?

Comment: @Leahcim although I provided a similar answer to fix this, I would also consider just leveraging `class="ng-hide"` and `ng-show="removeheaderflag"`. Unless you need to fully remove the DOM node. `ng-if` may be another approach as well

Comment: @Leahcim also I am unsure how much dom manipulation you are planning to do, but why not use `ng-class` bound to `removeheaderflag` with a `display: none`?

Comment: @salniro you are right `ng-show` or `ng-if` is an good idea.but as he is doing `.html('')` then `ng-if` is preferable. whats you opinion?

Comment: @PankajParkar I assume OP is just wanting to hide/show the element based on a flag. Going through CSS may prove the cleanest solution. Just a thought.. I updated my answer with a simple example. Please feel free to share your thoughts as well!

Answer (score 2):

Can you just check the returned value in your `$observe` for the value you wish- in this case, `true`? Observe the following change...

```
attrs.$observe('removeheaderflag', function(value) { // -- we know this
    if(value) {
        angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('.blahClassName')).html('');
    } 
});
```

Additionally, per discussion in comments, you may be able to take alternative approaches for this. Since your DOM manipulation is simple (in this example), leveraging [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and allowing CSS to handle this for us may prove a viable solution. Why not bind `headerflag` to a class with a `display: none` rule? An example could include... (kind of making up an example here in regards to markup)...

```
<header class="blahClassName" ng-class="{'remove': headerflag}">header</header>
```

---

```
.remove {
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.headerflag = true;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zmne4cs9/) - example with ngClass

Other approaches such as [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) may be applicable here as well. Perhaps you don't need a custom directive to accomplish this.

Comment: I beated you by 16 sec :p

Comment: Thank you to you too @salniro (I gave you both an upvote but will accept PankajParker's answer because he was first). . Do you agree with this approach to set state on the controller and listen/observe changes to the state in the directive to then do dom manipulation?

Comment: @salniro Yes.. That was really very small difference where we added an answer.. And we both caught an good on OP question :)

Comment: commented on neighboring answer because of the open dialog. See if those suggestions could be valuable in any way?

Comment: @Leahcim I added some alternative ideas that may be useful for this. Please check them out and let me know your thoughts

Comment: thank you for the information. I am trying out the alternatives you proposed. at the very least they are good to know.